# Unable to use datetimestrip for a particular value in the dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime-format, valueerror

So I am trying to convert dob to age this is my code:

```py
from datetime import *
def age(users_dob):
  users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, "%d/%m/%y").date()
  today = date.today()
  return today.year - users_dob.year - ((today.month,today.day) < (users_dob.month,users_dob.day))

age('17-04-1969')
```

But I am unable to do so on this date alone

The error I get is:

```
ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" % 
time data '17-04-1969' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'
```

I even tried to parse it separately but it isn't working.

Comment: Date format passed to the function is `'17-04-1969'` but the format string is `"%d/%m/%y"` disparity in the `-` vs `/` is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting for users_dob is off, I have changed the dob from '17-04-1969' to '17/04/69'

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def age(users_dob):
  users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, "%d/%m/%y").date()
  today = date.today()
  return today.year - users_dob.year - ((today.month,today.day) < (users_dob.month,users_dob.day))

print(age('17/04/69'))
```

result:

```
52
```

If you want to change the format in the 5th line instead, the correct format that will accept '17-04-1969' is '%d-%m-%Y', code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def age(users_dob):
  users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, '%d-%m-%Y').date()
  today = date.today()
  return today.year - users_dob.year - ((today.month,today.day) < (users_dob.month,users_dob.day))

print(age('17-04-1969'))
```

result:

```
52
```

Answer (score 1):

You face issue because of this line

`users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, "%d/%m/%y").date()`

it should be something like this

`users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, "%d-%m-%Y").date()`

**Final Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date


def age(users_dob):
  users_dob = datetime.strptime(users_dob, "%d-%m-%Y").date()
  today = date.today()
  return today.year - users_dob.year - ((today.month,today.day) < (users_dob.month,users_dob.day))

age = age('17-04-1969')

print(age)
```

**Output: 52**